# Practical NLP questions CrossValidated, Data Science, or Neither

Tags: support

I have a very specific question that might actually be rejected at both places.  I, for one, have tried to push through an NLP site on StackExchange but such approaches tend to be merged and don't survive.

So my question has to do with named entity recognition.  Are links typically tagged as named entities?  For example, if I have a link Obama.jpg, would that be counted as an entity (a person entity) or not.  So assuming that this is an answerable question, where would it best go?

Comment: NLP? Neuro-linguistic programming?

Comment: Sorry, natural language processing

Comment: I have no idea what your example question about Obama.jpg means, but we have a [natural-language](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language) tag so presumably natural language processing questions should be on topic.

Answer (score 4):

Natural language processing is on topic here, as @amoeba points out. But I think it'd be a good idea to clarify the point of your question in its body. Do you want to know *how* to recognize named entities within HTML links (given the lack of usual orthographic or syntactic clues)? Asking what [NER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) typically involves is a bit wishy-washy - it's likely to depend on the application.